# Guice volatile one of the injected property

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Im trying to build some ConfigurationService which will supply configuration with some injections.I want to make one of the property to be volatile while running.

Id like to achive something like this but I don 't know how to do this in Guice.

Guice module:

```
public class ConfModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        // how to bind class to itself, without any specific implementation
        bind(Property1.class).to(Property1.class);
        bind(IProperty2.class).to(Iproperty2DefaultImplementation1.class);
        bind(IProperty2.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("setterOfproperty2").to( ? ? ? );
    }
}
```

Conf class:

```
public class Conf {

    @Inject // just consatant injected property1.class
    private Property1 property1;

    // variable property impl of interface
    private IProperty2 property2;

    // default impl of interface from module binding
    @Inject
    public Conf(IProperty2 property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    // method for changing implementation
    @Inject
    public setIProperty2(@Named("setterOfproperty2") IProperty2 property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }
}
```

Conf service class:

```
public class ConfService {

    @Inject
    Conf configuration;


    public Conf getConf() {
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static main() {

    // return Conf with default IProperty2 impl
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ConfModule());
    ConfService c = injector.getInstance(ConfService.class);

    // change to other Iproperty2Implementation
    c.getConf().setIProperty2(new Iproperty2Implementation2());
}
```

Would anyone want to help me ?

Comment: Are you asking how to provide multiple possible bindings which can be dynamically chosen from at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that it was called that

Comment: It isn’t necessarily called that. I just wanted to clarify because `volatile` is a Java keyword.

Comment: What you want is a provider binding. Instead o binding and interface to a specific implementation class, it allows you to bind to a class that  is essentially a factory class. See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings